# How to use awk to print a particular section of input file

Tags: file, awk

I have an input file like this.

```
#
#mdrun is part of G R O M A C S:
#
#Go Rough, Oppose Many Angry Chinese Serial killers
#
@    title "dH/d\xl\f{}, \xD\f{}H"
@    xaxis  label "Time (ps)"
@ s0 legend "dH/d\xl\f{} \xl\f{} 0.1"
@ s1 legend "\xD\f{}H \xl\f{} 0.05"
@ s2 legend "\xD\f{}H \xl\f{} 0.15"
0.0000 -33.8598 1.71168 -1.66746
0.2000 -34.3949 1.73192 -1.702
0.4000 -31.8213 1.61262 -1.56193
0.6000 -32.3563 1.63639 -1.59224
0.8000 -33.6158 1.69898 -1.65539
1.0000 -32.5242 1.65055 -1.59363
1.2000 -33.7464 1.70708 -1.6607
1.4000 -33.0552 1.68563 -1.60985
1.6000 -32.9946 1.66834 -1.62445
1.8000 -31.6345 1.60933 -1.54529
2.0000 -33.1246 1.67736 -1.62769
2.2000 -33.9822 1.71743 -1.67394
2.4000 -32.4887 1.64732 -1.59384
2.6000 -30.0927 1.5349 -1.46508 
so on till 100000.0000
```

I want to generate a new file containing particular section( complete lines) say 1000.0000-2000.0000 with all the line containing "@" and "#". Somebody suggested me use awk and suggested this code.

```
  awk '(/^1000/,/^2000/) || /^[@#]/{print;}' inputfile > outputfile
```

which shows an error.

```
  awk: line 1: syntax error at or near ||
```

I haven't used awk before so I have no idea how to write code in awk.  If somebody can suggest how to write a proper code in awk or any other like sed. I will be grateful.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot combine the range operator `,` with `||` in this way, although there is an alternative in this case:

```
awk '/^1000/,/^2000/; /^[@#]/' inputfile > outputfile
```

The semicolon separates the two conditions. For each condition that is true, the default action (print the line) is carried out. This would be a problem if your conditions clashed (you would get duplicate lines in your output) but that doesn't apply here.

More generally, you can use a variable to determine which lines to print:

```
awk '/^1000/{f=1} f||/^[@#]/; /^2000/{f=0}' inputfile > outputfile
```

This deals with the case where the two separate conditions may both be true at the same time.

Comment: Nice, Works for me !!